# Why does visual studio crashes on opening a solution because of environment variable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual studio 2010 with SP1 crashes on opening a solution. Debugged visual studio and following was the thrown exception.

Following is the exception log:

```
MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Environment variable name or value is too long.
=============
System.ArgumentException: Environment variable name or value is too long.
   at System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String variable, String value)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.InProcNode.HandleShutdown(Exception& exception)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.InProcNode.Run(Exception& shutdownException)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that environment variable on the machine was too long got rid of some unecessary ones.